# how to share data in face book

Tags: codeigniter

I had done face book connect in my site for users to log in. Me want a feature to post a comment automatically on user's face book wall,when users logged to my site . This message should be like

You are connected to "site name" and "url" of site.

How it is possible in codeigniter .

Answer (score 0):

Check [this forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/187822/). Facebook Ignited is really easy and cool!